# Milestone associated with Beta badge

Tags: discussion, badges

Have we hit a milestone or something. Are we a public beta now? I see 33 people as of now have been awarded the beta badge. The requirements for most would have been met a while ago.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, we are now in public Beta as of 12:26 CST.  Woot!

Comment: Yeah. I saw I my mail a couple of minutes ago. My poor mod tools are gone now.

Comment: @Matt Ya, I was a 'Trusted User' for about 24 hours!  Now I need to double what I had to get it back...